# Atmega328p datasheet mistake "OCRA"

Tags: avr, atmega, timer, datasheet, atmega328p

I was reading the atmega328p [datasheet](http://chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/SMD/ATMega328.pdf), and suddenly, i saw that a register is mentioned called "OCRA", on page 108 and page 160, which normally, should be register "OCR0A", which is widely mentioned on this datasheet. "OCRA" is only mentioned on those two pages, inside tables, which is suspicious.

OCR0A is normally responsible for the TOP value of compare register for the timer interrups.

Is this a mistake of the datasheet?

Comment: Since it appears in a table, it might just be shorthand for OCRnA of the timer being described.  Or maybe it comes from an earlier idea of nomenclature that was changed everywhere else before publication.  Could be inherited from an earlier part only having one timer, but not immediately identifying the candidate.

Comment: Very likely a mistake. But OCRA is common for all timers, so not such an obvious error.